# Get all classes in the com dll

Tags: c#, reflection, com, tlbinf32

I have a com dll written in vb6. I need to write c# code that wil get me a list of all the classes within it.

My Objective is to get the classes and generate the classes in .net with all the properties and create a mapping class.

I just need to get a list of classes from the dll.

Summary:
How can I get a list of all the classes in my com dll?

Comment: If you for some reason can't use out-of-the-box functionality from VS, this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/523417/Reflection-with-IDispatch-based-COM-objects and this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347981.aspx will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection to walk the Interop for your COM DLL will give you classes and interfaces that a vaguely analogous to COM CoClasses and interfaces.

If quick and easy is what you're after, add your COM DLL as a reference in Visual Studio and use the code below to walk through the Interop assembly looking for classes. If it's a VB6 COM DLL everything is going to be IDispatch anyway, but you could optionally filter on objects with a CoClass, Guid or InterfaceType attributes on the types identified below (you didn't specify whether you were after classes or CoClasses).

```
var classes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyComDLL.RandomTypeFromWithin))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.IsClass);
```

If you're trying to really do this properly, the articles Dennis linked to in his comment are better, as is p/Invoke'ing LoadTypeLib and walking ITypeLib (the latter option being non-trivial).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `TLBINF32.dll`. It is a COM component that ships with most versions of Windows. Make sure it is registered using `regsvr32.exe` from an elevated command prompt (along with your COM dll). Reference it in your .NET app (compiled to x86) and use the `TLIApplication.TypeLibInfoFromFile` method. From there you can traverse the type library of the COM component and get the classes, methods, interfaces, and properties exposed.

We use this library for various utilities.

Comment: Seems this library is no longer available in Windows 10. Are there any other ways to implement such functionality; for instance by using the Windows API?

Comment: The latest version works with Windows 10. We use it as part of a build process. I don't know what licensing restrictions there might be but as far as just raw functionality it works fine.